# javascript keep checkbox checked after refresh page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

hi i am javascript newbie.

I have checkbox that slideDown other input , i want to keep that checkbox checked and the other input showed after refreshing the page if the input checkbox checked

**javascript:**

```
function validateSitec(){
if (document.getElementById('sitecheck').checked){
$('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
$('#closedmsg').slideDown();
}else{
$('#closedmsg').slideUp();
$("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
}
}
```

**this my inputs:**

```
<label for="sitecheck">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">close site+ msg:</span>
</label>
<input name="" type="checkbox" id="sitecheck" onclick="validateSitec()" /><span style="font-weight:bold;">click to activate msg</span><br>
<input type="text" name="closedmsg" id="closedmsg" style="width:440px;height:120px;display:none;" value="enter closed msg.."/>
```

i want if checked stay checked.. and wont change after refreshing the page , then when unchecked so back to normal and be unchecked when refreshing the page..

should i use php for making it not change after checking with javascript?

**Edited:**

Thanks to all for helping
credit goes to : leiyonglin .

The working code for anyone who like to use it:

download first:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

then use this codes working awesome :

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateSitec(){
if (document.getElementById('sitecheck').checked){
    $('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
    $('#closedmsg').slideDown();
    $.cookie("cookieChecked", "#sitecheck");
}else{
    $('#closedmsg').slideUp();
    $("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked");
    $.cookie("cookieChecked","");
}
}


  $(function(){
      var cookieChecked = $.cookie("cookieChecked");
      if(cookieChecked){
          $('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
          $('#closedmsg').show();
      }else{
          $("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked");
          $('#closedmsg').hide();
      }
 })
    </script>
```

html inputs:

```
<label for="sitecheck">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">close site temp:</span>
</label>
<input name="" type="checkbox" id="sitecheck" onclick="validateSitec()" /><span style="font-weight:bold;">close site and add message</span><br>
<input type="text" name="closedmsg" id="closedmsg" style="width:440px;height:120px;display:none;" value="<?php echo $data['csitemsg']; ?>" />
```

This working perfect thx again all.

Comment: you could use cookies to store which checkbox was selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set cookies:
Save the checked element in cookieChecked

```
function validateSitec(){
if (document.getElementById('sitecheck').checked){
    $('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
    $('#closedmsg').slideDown();
    $.cookie("cookieChecked", "#sitecheck");
}else if(document.getElementById('closedmsg').checked){
    $('#closedmsg').slideUp();
    $("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
    $.cookie("cookieChecked", "#closedmsg");
} else {
    $.cookie("cookieChecked","");
}
}
```

When page onload

```
 $(function(){
      var cookieChecked = $.cookie("cookieChecked");
      if(cookieChecked){
          $(cookieChecked).trigger("click");
      }
 })
```

I use the jquery cookie plugin : https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: working exept when i uncheck its keep bieng checked and idea?

Comment: reset cookie value when nothing checked

Comment: ok awesome i fixed the code any edit my question so anyone can use it thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie to maintain your data on page refresh by using cookie. I notice you are using JQuery in your  code. Here is a `JQuery-Cookie` plugin which will let you use cookie to manage your data across page refresh.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Go to **Usage** section and you will find how to create, read, delete and set expire easily form the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the page refresh event and store the status of check box in cache or local storage. After refresh completes based on the checked status perform your logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not use additional plugin:

```
<script>
    function validateSitec(){
        if (document.getElementById('sitecheck').checked){
            $('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
            $('#closedmsg').slideDown();
            document.cookie="sitecheck=site_checked";
        }else{
            $('#closedmsg').slideUp();
            $("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
            document.cookie="sitecheck=site_unchecked";
        }
    }
</script>
```

When document ready:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
      var kuki=read_cookie("sitecheck");
      if(kuki=="site_checked"){
            $('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
            $('#closedmsg').slideDown();
      }else{
            $('#closedmsg').slideUp();
            $("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
      }
 });
</script>
```

Read cookies

```
<script>
function read_cookie(name) {
    var name = name + "=";
    var kukiAri = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < kukiAri.length;i++) { 
        var kuki = kukiAri[i];
        while (kuki.charAt(0)==' ') kuki = kuki.substring(1,kuki.length);
        if (kuki.indexOf(name) == 0)
                return kuki.substring(name.length,kuki.length);
    }
    return null;
};
</script>
```