# How to keep Checkboxes checked after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, local-storage

I have around **50+ checkboxes** in one form. If user by chance typed wrong `Captcha`, whole page got refreshed and then they've to again re-select all choices through checkboxes. Now, I want to save user's selected option on `localStorage`.

After research, I found the this solution which isn't useful in my case, since the following code saves the `Checkbox` status and it applies to all the checkboxes available on page.

**HTML/ PHP Code:**

```
<label for="<?php echo $val;?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="CuisineTags[]" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" id="<?php echo $val; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> class="addCuisineItem"/>
    <span class="cuisine-name"><?php echo $val; ?></span>
</label>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$(function(){
    var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Please help. What is the best solution regarding aforementioned problem.

Comment: This question has been already asked. Check this anwser here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247264/javascript-keep-checkbox-checked-after-refresh-page