# Keeping a checkbox checked after refreshing the page

Tags: html, checkbox

I have some checkboxes in my php page.when ever i check some of them,some divs get hidden,some get visible.but when i refresh the page,checkboxes get unchecked.and all div s are visible then.
How to keep checkboxes checked even after refreshing the page..?

I tried code as below

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.10.0.js"></script>
        <script src=".jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="tests.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var cookieChecked = $.cookie("cookieChecked");
  if(cookieChecked){
      $(cookieChecked).trigger("click");
  }
 })
</script> 
        </head>
        <body>



<label for="sitecheck">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">close site temp:</span>
</label>
<input name="" type="checkbox" id="sitecheck" onclick="validateSitec()" /><span style="font-weight:bold;">close site and add message</span><br>
<input type="text" name="closedmsg" id="closedmsg" style="width:440px;height:120px;display:none;" value="<?php echo $data['csitemsg']; ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateSitec(){
if (document.getElementById('sitecheck').checked){
    $('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
    $('#closedmsg').slideDown();
    $.cookie("cookieChecked", "#sitecheck");
}else if(document.getElementById('closedmsg').checked){
    $('#closedmsg').slideUp();
    $("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
    $.cookie("cookieChecked", "#closedmsg");
} else {
    $.cookie("cookieChecked","");
}
}


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to store it somewhere, are those checkboxes in a <form> tag so you can use $_POST or $_GET with PHP? or store it in a cookie which would be the clientside but not everyone is allowing cookies

Comment: Then how to handle it without cookies????

Comment: How will you "refresh" the page?

Answer (score 0):

checboxes wont stay ticked on page refresh by default but you can check out the jquery cookie plugin or check out  [keep checkbox ticked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247264/javascript-keep-checkbox-checked-after-refresh-page) page

Use this Sample code from there

javascript

```
function validateSitec(){
if (document.getElementById('sitecheck').checked){
    $('#sitecheck').prop('checked', true);
    $('#closedmsg').slideDown();
    $.cookie("cookieChecked", "#sitecheck");
}else if(document.getElementById('closedmsg').checked){
    $('#closedmsg').slideUp();
    $("#sitecheck").removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
    $.cookie("cookieChecked", "#closedmsg");
} else {
    $.cookie("cookieChecked","");
}
}
```

and on page load

```
 $(function(){
  var cookieChecked = $.cookie("cookieChecked");
  if(cookieChecked){
      $(cookieChecked).trigger("click");
  }
 })
```

Comment: i tried this.but still not working.i imported all the scripts as well

Comment: remember to place the function validateSite after the form or div holding it and the other function in the head of the webpage. also include jquery in your sitr. still having problems maybe you shoul include some code in your question..

Comment: @Andewumi-included the code which i tried,just check where i m doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

well as you are not showing any of your code we actually shouldn't post any answer cause everything is just a guess.

If you don't want to save it in a cookie you could save it in a session, which is better cause it is server side.

So with this solution you have to check the checkboxes and click on the submit button. If you don't like that you could change that to an ajax call. Also you have to change some stuff if you wan't to have it work if your user is leaving your page and coming back....

So this is just to give you an idea how your PHP could be looking:

-lets say your checkboxes come from an array. in the example the array is called `$valuesForInput[]`

```
<?php

session_start();


if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
    $_SESSION['check'] = $_POST['check'];
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['check']);
    session_destroy();
}


$valuesForInput[] = "one";
$valuesForInput[] = "two";
$valuesForInput[] = "three";

$html = '
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <div>';
            foreach($valuesForInput as $k => $v) {
                if(is_array($_SESSION['check'])) {
                    $check = in_array($v, $_SESSION['check']) ? ' checked' : '';
                }
                $html.='
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$v.'"'.$check.'>
                    <label for="check1">'.$v.'</label>
                ';
            } $html.='
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
';


echo $html;
?>
```

have fun coding

Comment: Thanks @caramba-i tried some other code,which i updated in my post.please check that once..

Answer (score -1):

Try this one i think this one will work.we can keep the check box after refreshing the page also

```
 <?php 

     $val=  $_POST['checkbox1']; 


  ?>


 <li>  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1[]" value="sradha" <?php if (strpos($val, "sradha") !== false) {  ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />
<label>sradha</label></li>
```

It should work